# GemBox Word Document to Email ,£ character is converted to question mark

Tags: character-encoding, gembox-document, gembox-email

GemBox Word Document to Email, convert £ character to question mark for one of my clients.

my code I same as on gembox site.

`GemBox.Document.ComponentInfo.SetLicense(this.GemBoxDocumentLisense);
 GemBox.Email.ComponentInfo.SetLicense(this.GemBoxEmailLisense);

 var document = DocumentModel.Load(documentPath);
 using (MemoryStream gemBoxOutput = new MemoryStream())
 {
document.Save(gemBoxOutput , new GemBox.Document.HtmlSaveOptions()
{
    HtmlType = GemBox.Document.HtmlType.Mhtml,
    UseContentIdHeaders = true,
  //Encoding = Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
});
MailMessage.Load(gemBoxOutput, MailMessageFormat.Mhtml);`


I want to set utf-8 encoding using gembox without destroying template.I tried to set the encoding in htmlsaveoptions but it destroy the template and the email is not properly loaded in outlook.

Comment: Can you share the file that is in the "documentPath" path? Perhaps you have a TXT file that is written in "Windows-1252" encoding. That could cause this issue because by default the TxtLoadOptions will use UTF8 encoding.

Comment: That is basicaly .docx file

Comment: Then I'm not sure what problem you have, the DOCX files are written in UTF8 encoding. Also, the default encoding in HtmlSaveOptions is UTF8.

Comment: That problem is only with one of my client's server.when ever thy receive email it convert pond symbol to a diamond question mark. any suggestions.

Comment: @MarioZ I want to set utf-8 encoding using gembox without destroying template.I tried to set the encoding in htmlsaveoptions but it destroy the template and the email is not properly loaded in outlook.

Comment: You are using the UTF8 encoding, your problem is that the input is not UTF8 for some reason. I'm afraid that in order to resolve your issue I would need to be able to reproduce it. Can you share a small project that can reproduce your problem?